# Remove color cast in darktable?

Tags: color-correction, darktable

I'm playing with Darktable, coming from Photoshop, and though I really admire most of its features, there is one thing I cannot seem to wrap my head around.

In Photoshop, I can easily remove color cast using the 'Auto Color' command, which basically applies Levels to stretch each of the color channels. Alternatively, I can manually play with Levels per channel. In Darktable, I have yet to find an equivalent way to remove a color cast. What is an effective Darktable approach here?

Comment: Out of interest, why did you choose PS and Darktable over Lightroom?

Comment: Well, aside from the white balance module, there's also color correction, color balance, color contrast, color zones, channel mixer. Any of them can work for removing color casts - some better for full-image casts vs just e.g. in the shadows or something. The best way to figure out what works best for you is to play with them.

Comment: @Tim Stack: I own a PS license, am less and less happy with Adobe so will definitely not invest in Lightroom.

Comment: Aah. Well, what can I say? Arr, drink up me harties!

Answer (score 15):

Within the [white balance module](https://darktable.gitlab.io/doc/en/modules.html#whitebalance) you can select "spot" from the preset drop-down list to remove color cast based on a selected area. By default, the entire image except for a margin around the edges is selected; better results are usually obtained by selecting a part of the image that should be neutral gray or white (be careful about including any areas with clipped highlights, though, as this can throw off the calculation).

Comment: What is a clipped highlight? Google results are too broad on that topic.

Answer (score 5):

For manual channel-by-channel adjustment, you could try the [color balance module](https://www.darktable.org/usermanual/en/color_group.html#d0e8958). I don't think it's enabled by default, so you may need to activate it using the "more modules" button.

Comment: This comes closest to what I was looking for...

Comment: Note that the [latest versions of this module](https://darktable.gitlab.io/doc/en/color_group.html#color_balance) include a "neutralize colors" button near the bottom, but despite being a "dropper" button, it seems to not actually let you select a specific region.